# Spring-Integration: int-http:outbound-channel-adapter using json

Tags: json, http, type-conversion, spring-integration

I want to use the `int-http:outbound-channel-adapter` calling my rest service, but unfortunately it doesnt want to convert my pojo to json.

My Configuration:

```
<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="ticketOutgoingChannel"
    http-method="PUT"
    url="http://localhost:8080/process/ticket"
    expected-response-type="*.model.Ticket"
    message-converters="converters"
/>

<util:list id="converters">
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
</util:list>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [*.model.Ticket] and content type [application/x-java-serialized-object]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:810)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:594)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:493)
at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:382)
... 34 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[application/x-java-serialized-object]`

This is the default content type for a Java object if no `contentType` header is provided.

Use

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="ticketOutgoingPreProcessChannel" 
       output-channel="ticketOutgoingChannel">
    <int:header name="contentType" value="application/json" overwrite="true/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

to instruct the adapter to convert to JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I chose the `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>` cos I dont expect a response. Could you please explain a little how I should use the `<int:header-filter>`, maybe a small example would be great.

I use a `<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>` what sends the pojo into the integration-context. So I guess it get there the header set to x-java-serialized-object.

Comment: My mistake - that is the default `contentType` if none is provided. See my edit. `> I dont expect a response` - in that case, you don't need an `expected-response-type` - that is what threw me.

Comment: Awesome, that works. Thanks.Btw. the message-converter is not needed more, too.

Comment: Yes, we configure a JSON converter by default (and a bunch of others).